# How to Add Related Posts' Function after first paragraph in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this code to display adsense ad after the first paragraph of single post. And, it works flawlessly.

```html
/** Add adsense after first paragraph **/
function insert_ad_block( $text ) {

    if ( is_single() ) :

        $ads_text = '<p class="middle_content">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 300x250, created 4/20/09 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>


</p>';
        $split_by = "\n";
        $insert_after = 1; //number of paragraphs

        // make array of paragraphs
        $paragraphs = explode( $split_by, $text);

        // if array elements are less than $insert_after set the insert point at the end
        $len = count( $paragraphs );
        if (  $len < $insert_after ) $insert_after = $len;

        // insert $ads_text into the array at the specified point
        array_splice( $paragraphs, $insert_after, 0, $ads_text );

        // loop through array and build string for output
        foreach( $paragraphs as $paragraph ) {
            $new_text .= $paragraph; 
        }

        return $new_text;

    endif;

    return $text;

}
add_filter('the_content', 'insert_ad_block');
```

But now I also add some related posts just below the ad, but can't find out how to do it.

In fact I want to add this function in this code.

```
if(function_exists('yarpp_related')) yarpp_related(array('limit' => 2));
```

If I replace the Ad code with this functions like this:

```
$ads_text = yarpp_related(array('limit' => 2));
```

Then I get the related posts entries two times, one at the beginning of the post and one after the first paragraph. What should I do that the related posts show only once after the first paragraph?

please help me how to get it done.